# UI Controls Invalid obviously Model is Valid

Tags: wpf, validation, data-binding

I got a Model named Box with a Customer Property which is decorated with the Required DataAnnotation.

```
public class Box : ValidatableBindableBase
{
        protected Customer _Customer;
        [Required]
        public virtual Customer Customer
        {
            get { return _Customer; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _Customer, value); }
        }
}
```

Note: The ValidatableBindableBase is mainly taken from https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/async-validation-wpf-prism

In the UI there is a ComboBox and a Button. The Combobox ItemsSource is a list of Customers which will be filled by a service call at program start up.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"  
                    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentBox.Customer,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

The Customers property of the Box is at program start NULL. Therefore the Combobox got a red border (Invalid). The user have to click on a Button which will execute the OnBoxCommand. This will do also a service call and set the Customer property of the CurrentBox.

```
public DelegateCommand<String> BoxCommand { get; private set; }

protected async void OnBoxCommand()
{
     CurrentBox.Customer = (await _ServiceCall.GetCustomer());
}
```

After the OnBoxCommand is executed the ComboBox got still a red border obviously the Customer is set in the UI. When I use the Debugger after the `_ServiceCall.GetCustomer();` line, I see that the CurrentBox.HasErrors is false, and the CurrentBox.Customer is set. I also tried to add to the binding "ValidatesOnException=True" and called CurrentBox.ValidateProperties();

After some hours I found a solution by assigning the value of the ServiceCall in a task.

```
protected async void OnBoxCommand()
{
     var bla = (await _ServiceCall.GetCustomer());
     new Task(() => this.CurrentBox.Customer = bla).Start();
}
```

I dont't know why the validation of the wpf Control got not updated without the Task. Has someone an idea of this strange behavior and can explain me why I need to use `new Task(() => this.CurrentBox = bla).Start();`

Comment: What is `CurrentBox`? And why dont you set the Customer?

Comment: I'm sry, I fixed the Code Snippet. CurrentBox is of type Box.

Answer (score 0):

`await _ServiceCall.GetCustomer();` will return `Task<Customer>`. to get the customers from the service call then you have to call the result of the task  ike

```
protected async void OnBoxCommand()
{
     this.CurrentBox = await _ServiceCall.GetCustomer().Result;

}
```